# How do I generalize two or more .csv imported on neo4j and how do I calculate the critical path method for each graph?

Tags: python, csv, neo4j, cypher

I have several graphics created in .csv {Task1,Task2,Task3,ecc} and imported on neo4j using Python.
This is an example:

GRAPH 1

```
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  'file:///A2_new.csv' AS line "\
  "CREATE (node:Task1 { ID: line.ID, attivita: line.attivita, descrizione: line.descrizione, predecessori: SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';'), durata: toInt(line.durata), inizio: line.inizio, fine: line.fine, nick: line.nick, ruolo: line.ruolo, start: toInt(REPLACE(line.inizio,'-', '')), finish: toInt(REPLACE(line.fine,'-', '')) } )" \
  "WITH node, SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';') AS predecessors " \
  "MATCH (p:Task1) " \
  "WHERE p.ID IN predecessors " \
  "MERGE (p)-[:RELAZIONE]->(node) "
```

GRAPH2

```
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  'file:///B2_new.csv' AS line "\
  "CREATE (node:Task2 { ID: line.ID, attivita: line.attivita, descrizione: line.descrizione, predecessori: SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';'), durata: toInt(line.durata), inizio: line.inizio, fine: line.fine, nick: line.nick, ruolo: line.ruolo, start: toInt(REPLACE(line.inizio,'-', '')), finish: toInt(REPLACE(line.fine,'-', '')) } )" \
  "WITH node, SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';') AS predecessors " \
  "MATCH (p:Task2) " \
  "WHERE p.ID IN predecessors " \
  "MERGE (p)-[:RELAZIONE]->(node) "
```

First question. How do I remove redundancy and use the same code block for each .csv (considering that all .csv have the same fields as you can see from the code above)?

---

Second question.At this point, I should calculate the critical path method for each graph. I would like to always calculate generically for each graph.
How can I do and how do I get data from neo4j using Python

Thank you so much

Comment: There must be a way to provide a list of files to a python function that does the cypher accordingly

https://neo4j.com/developer/python/#_the_example_project

Answer (score 0):

You can just use unwind on the array of CSV files:

```
UNWIND ['file:///A2_new.csv','file:///A1_new.csv'] as file
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  file AS line "\
  "CREATE (node:Task1 { ID: line.ID, attivita: line.attivita, descrizione: line.descrizione, predecessori: SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';'), durata: toInt(line.durata), inizio: line.inizio, fine: line.fine, nick: line.nick, ruolo: line.ruolo, start: toInt(REPLACE(line.inizio,'-', '')), finish: toInt(REPLACE(line.fine,'-', '')) } )" \
  "WITH node, SPLIT(line.predecessori, ';') AS predecessors " \
  "MATCH (p:Task1) " \
  "WHERE p.ID IN predecessors " \
  "MERGE (p)-[:RELAZIONE]->(node)
```

You can use Neo4j from Python with the python driver, see http://neo4j.com/developer/python

For the critical path, you would have to explain a bit more.

The longest path is:

```
MATCH path = (start:Task {ID:$start})-[:RELAZIONE*]->(end:Task)
WHERE NOT (end)-[:RELAZIONE]->()
RETURN path
```

Comment: 1) as far as the first question is concerned. I need to create a graph for each "file: /// .csv". With the solution you provided me, i find a single concatenated graph between the two "files: /// .csv".

2)For CPM.Once you have created the graphs, i should calculate the critical path for each of them.I used this solution, both for Task1 and Task2. I would also like to parameterize it in this case.
`MATCH p = (:Task1 {attivita:'Start'})-[:RELAZIONE*]->(:Task1 {attivita:'Finish'}) WITH p, REDUCE(x = 0, a IN NODES(p) | x + a.durata) AS cum_duration ORDER BY cum_duration DESC LIMIT 1 RETURN p`

Comment: Another additional question. I have another "file: /// .csv" of this type:
`"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM  'file:///C.csv' AS line "\
      "CREATE (node:Risorse { ID: line.ID, nickname: line.nickname, risorsa: line.risorsa, ruolo: SPLIT(line.ruolo, ';')} )"`
where i've information about people working on various activities (shared resources for both Task1 and Task2, and any Task3, Task4 etc).
I would like to relate these people "for example: WORKON" with the various activities of Task1, Task2, etc. Of course I have to link them to each graph. Using the nickname property, how can I do it??

Comment: Shouldn't your task-id's be different for the two graphs? you could also add a prefix/suffix per file to the task-ids while creating/matching them.

Comment: Just don't use that prefix then for people and other shared resources :)

Comment: can you provide me with code examples for the question of the comments above, please? Thank you very much

Comment: just use e.g. `filename + line.ID` as id for the tasks in separate networks